# assigning css class to form element passed from flask to jinja

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am quite new to jinja / flask, I am creating dymnamic form in my flask app:

```
class CreateForm(FlaskForm):
    searchCity = StringField('View forcast of city:', validators=[InputRequired("Please enter the city you want to check weather updates")])
    count = IntegerField("Days")
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")


form = CreateForm(request.form)
form.count.default = count
form.count.label = "Days" if count > 1 else "Day" 

form.count.data = count
```

and in jinja template:

```
<form>
    <dl>
        <dd>{{ form.searchCity.label }} {{ form.searchCity(size=20) }} 
            for next {{ form.count(size=2) }} {{ form.count.label }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Submit" id="calculate" onclick="getWeatherForcaset(
            document.getElementsByName('searchCity')[whole_number].value,
            document.getElementsByName('count')[whole_number].value
            );" >
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <input type="checkbox" name="exactMatch" checked="checked">Exact Match 
            &nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember<br/ >
        </dd>

    </dl>
 </form>
```

I want to assign class `form-group` to `searchCity` inputbox !
any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the first `<input>` tag? Does doing `class="btn-primary form-group"` not work?

Comment: Hello @mangoHero1 if you look above in the code I do not have input field normally set the usual way , I am creating the input field from python and passing to jinja `form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass variables into the constructor like so

```
{{ form.searchCity(size=20, class_='searchCity') }}
```

Documentation is available at :

http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crash_course.html#rendering-fields

Doc Snippet

> However, the real power comes from rendering the field with its
>   **call**() method. By calling the field, you can provide keyword arguments, which will be injected as html attributes in the output:
>
> form.content(style="width: 200px;", class_="bar")

```
<input class="bar" id="content" name="content" style="width: 200px;" type="text" value="foobar" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

In **WTForms 2.1** I using `extra_classes`, like the line bellow:

**1. The first way**

```
{{ f.render_form_field(form.searchCity, extra_classes='ourClasses') }}
```

or maybe in your case just like this:

```
{{ form.searchCity, extra_classes='form-group' }}
```

We can also use the `render_kw` attribute on our form field like the second way below:

**2. The second way**

```
style={'class': 'form-group', 'style': 'we can also add another css style here'}
searchCity = StringField('View forcast of city:',
                         validators=[InputRequired("Please enter the city you want to check weather updates")],
                         render_kw=style)
```

But I would like more prefer to use the first way.