# Flask / Python3.7 jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'page'

Tags: ubuntu, flask, jinja2, python-3.7

I have a simple Flask endpoint that fetch data from sqlite3, and split result in pages.

Even with empty data, it was showing empty table as it should.

I installed python3.7 on a new VPS, installed the requirements, but now I get this error, which I never had and that not happen when I run the same code locally.

```
File "/bot/templates/show_items.html", line 17, in top-level template code
    </a>,<a href="{{ url_for('show_items', page=items.page) }}">Refresh</a>,<a href="./export/">Export All</a>,<a href="./deleteAll/">Del. All (watch out)</a>)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 345, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1774, in build
    rv = self._partial_build(endpoint, values, method, append_unknown)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1689, in _partial_build
    append_unknown)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1697, in _partial_build
    rv = rule.build(values, append_unknown)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 809, in build
    add(self._converters[data].to_url(values[data]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1034, in to_url
    value = self.num_convert(value)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'page'
```

The template where it fail:

```
<h3>(<a href = "{{ url_for('new') }}">Add Items
     </a>,<a href="{{ url_for('show_items', page=items.page) }}">Refresh</a>,<a href="./export/">Export All</a>,<a href="./delet$

   </h3>
```

The enpoint:

```
@app.route("/", defaults={'page': 1}, methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/<int:page>/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_items(page):

  try:

    itemss = items.query.order_by("lastUpdate desc, idI desc").paginate(page, 10)
  except:
    itemss = []
  return render_template('show_items.html', items = itemss )
```

I obliviously checked other stack questions, sadly nothing seems related, I tried that but it show no data when the database is full of : [jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'username'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894685/jinja2-exceptions-undefinederror-str-object-has-no-attribute-username)

Answer (score 0):

The code must be entering the except block and therefore items is an empty list, and not a pagination object. Put an if block in your template to handle the case where there are no items and you will get rid of the error.

```
<h3>(<a href = "{{ url_for('new') }}">Add Items</a>,

    {% if not items %}
    <a href="{{ request.url }}">Refresh</a>,
    {% else %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('show_items', page=items.page) }}">Refresh</a>,
    {% endif %}

     <a href="./export/">Export All</a>,<a href="./delet$}


 </h3>
```

Comment: Sorry for delay, I tried to do like : 
{% if not items %}
<a href="{{ url_for('show_items') }}">Refresh</a>
{% else %}
<a href="{{ url_for('show_items', page=items.page) }}">Refresh</a>
{% endif %}

Comment: But sadly the table show no items, when let's say exporting to csv actually output corretly the sqlite3 database in the csv file.

Comment: I see a possible syntax error - 'itemss' in your flask code has 2 s's but when you reference it in your template it has 1 s. Is that intentional?

Comment: See this line in endpoit : return render_template('show_items.html', items = itemss )

Comment: This was to prevent having the same value name, sorry for confusion. My whole code work on my own ubuntu machine with same python 3.7.0, but I think I have an older flask

Comment: Ok nvm. Well if you're certain there is data in your db table but you aren't receiving it in your template, there is a problem w/ the db connection or your query. But the error isn't specific to that. Are your other queries/paginations working?

Comment: I mean my whole code work locally but not on my vps, without changing anything. Also yes returning Csv file with the whole database content actually work, but its not using jinja2,just output the file itself.

Comment: Make sure all of your required dependencies and packages are installed on the VPS? Something that was on your local computer that is missing from the VPS?

Comment: I cared to write a requirements.txt and specify the same version of flask and jinja2 I have locally 